# Error trying to install Python using CMake

Tags: cmake

I am trying to build and install some Python code using CMake.
I got this error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (enable_langauge):
  Unknown CMake command "enable_langauge".
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

How do I get past it?

This is my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
##########################################
#Project setup
##########################################
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.9)
project(PothosAdderDemo)
enable_langauge(python)

find_package(Pothos CONFIG REQUIRED)
include(PothosPythonUtil)

##########################################
## Build and install
##########################################
POTHOS_PYTHON_UTIL(
    TARGET MyAdderBlock
    SOURCES
        __init__.py
        MyAdder.py
    FACTORIES
        "/my_package/adder:Adder"
    DESTINATION MyPackage
    ENABLE_DOCS
)
```

Comment: Looks like you have a typo. Try changing "enable_langauge" to "enable_language".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error output gives you a pretty strong hint as to what's causing the problem:

```
Unknown CMake command "enable_langauge".
```

The word "language" is misspelt; correcting the spelling should get you past this problem.